# Creating and using UDF in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I created UDF as mentioned in http://www.findnwrite.com/musings/extract-top-n-records-in-each-group-in-hadoophive/

After executing statement "create temporary function rank as 'com.example.hive.udf.Rank';"
I get the log as shown in  http://pastebin.com/hHFa9G9A

How do I interpret the log or how do I know whether function is created successfully?

Also when I execute the hive query using the function rank I get the exception as described in
http://pastebin.com/fP5LnyGG

Comment: Just to cover the bases, you did compile the jar and run 'add jar path/to/YourJar.jar;' right (where the path is relative to Hive's working directory)? Have you been able to successfully add and run a temporary function from a jar before?

Comment: @DanielKoverman If I add the jar from /user/hive/Rank.jar it throws me error(jar doesnot exist) and I added the jar from my local as "add jar /home/cloudera/Rank.jar" works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is solved

Couple of bugs in the article itself http://www.findnwrite.com/musings/extract-top-n-records-in-each-group-in-hadoophive/

Replaced the statements in the article with below statements

1)

```
Create Rank jar


jar -cf Rank.jar ./com/example/hive/udf/Rank.class
```

2)

```
SELECT user, category, value
FROM (
    SELECT user, category, rank(user) as rank, value
    FROM $compTable
    WHERE user is NOT NULL AND AND ctr > 0
    DISTRIBUTE BY user
    SORT BY user, value desc
) a
WHERE rank(user) < 5
ORDER BY user, rank(user)
```